# Silverlight filtering data with checkboxes like pivotviewer?

Tags: silverlight, filtering, ria

I'm building an internal file portal style app in silverlight,

I need to be able to filter the files by category using checkboxes like in pivotviewer:
[image]

To display the categories im using a ItemsControl, and am currently using a hacky workaround to store the category id.. so files can be added and removed appropriaely when somethings check or unchecked:

```
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="categoryList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                                <CheckBox Checked="categoryIncluded" Unchecked="categoryExcluded" Content="{Binding ID}">
                                    <CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <!-- This is a hack, content is being used to store the id of the category -->
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </CheckBox.ContentTemplate>
                                </CheckBox>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC2BDBD" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

This seems like a massive hack,

How is this normally done in silverlight?

(I'm using RIA data services by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that hack you could create custom control that conteins chekbox + other data and id property

Comment: Good suggestion.. was just wondering if theres already a way of doing it?

Comment: you could do it with your viewmodel bind IsCheked property and do notify filter whene this changes and because you are doing it in your viewmodel youalredy have id value there

Comment: Cool thanks.. I ended up subclassing checkbox and just adding the field :)